# WPF Browser Control gives an opacity animation issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Why I cannot animate the opacity of the WPF Browser Control?
I also tried to chanage the opacity of the upper object which is Canvas, but no success.

Is there some way to do it? Thank you!

```
var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.45)));
RootGrid.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, doubleAnimation);
MainBrowser.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, doubleAnimation);

 <Grid Background="Transparent"  Name="RootGrid"  >       
        <WebBrowser x:Name="MainBrowser"   />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no that is not supported. [This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scoberry/archive/2006/09/01/735844.aspx) explains the limitations when dealing with Interop content. But the section that applies is:

> Opacity/Layered Windows/AllowTransparency
>
> Setting Opacity on a WindowsFormsHost (setting AllowsTransparency on a
>   Window) will not work, since HwndHost doesn't support this.

Comment: Hmmm.. Why does WPF Browser Control handle this property "Opacity" then?

Comment: Because it is inheriting it from the base class [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.opacity.aspx).